# Flickering with IE10 SharePoint 2010 Modal Dialogs

Tags: sharepoint-2010, modal-dialog, internet-explorer-10

Has anyone else encountered an issue with Modal Dialogs in SharePoint 2010 with IE10?  Both OOB and custom modals when in IE10 normal or compatibility Browser Mode with IE8 Standards Document Mode causes constant flickering.  The modal grey that is supposed to be over the page will not be there initially, but then appear and start the flickering once you move your mouse off of the modal.  The issue appears to go away if I change the Document mode to IE9 mode.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?

Comment: Nope.  I did do some more digging and it appears to be something in the SharePoint javascript that is toggling the zindex and size properties of the modal overlay div repeatedly, but I am not sure why its being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.I added this to my CSS file and it removed the flicker.

```
body.v4master
{
 overflow:hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if You still have this problem this is my workaround. In Your script where You open dialog add

```
$(".ms-dlgOverlay").css({
    'position': 'relative'
});
```

This will hide the overlay. I couldn't make it work with visible overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `.ms-dlgOverlay` from `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;` fixed it for me.
BTW, this style is found in corev4.css file.